# WIX suppress uninstall dialog when doing a major upgrade?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

In one installer version of our product, I've added a custom dialog (shown by a CA using `session.Message()`) that asks the user if he wants to keep some of his data, at uninstall.

The CA has the condition set to `REMOVE="ALL" AND NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED`. 
The dialog is correctly shown when doing a normal uninstall, but it also appears when removing the existing product, at a major upgrade. At that point, the installer hangs and it can only be closed from the Task Manager, resulting in an incorrect upgrade.

The installer version, containing the issue, has already been shipped.
Is there something that we can include in the next installer version (that does a major upgrade), that solves the dialog issue when removing the existing product?

Answer (score 2):

The property UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE is set in the older product as it is being uninstalled. WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED is set in the incoming new upgrade setup when it detects.

A condition of REMOVE="ALL" AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE seems to be what you want, showing the dialog during unstall but not when the uninstall is because of a major upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know that now and I've set the flags accordingly, on the new version. The problem was with the previous version, which was already shipped with the wrong flags.

Comment: Chris's answer is what you need - change the cached MSI, or build a minor upgrade to updare the broken installed product.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the cached MSI of the original version.  There shouldn't be any UI during a silent installation transaction.  You'll need to make a copy of the original built MSI, modify it to not execute that custom action and then recache it using msiexec /I foo.msi REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus before you can do your major uprade.  Or, tell your users to do an uninstall first.  This is the reason you are supposed to test your servicing strategy before you go to production. MSI is like an airplane... there is not stop or go back button.  You are always moving forward and you have to plan accordingly.

Comment: I've created a CA in the newer version (major upgrade), which calls msiexec as you described (using the corrected msi). The action runs after FindRelatedProducts, but for some reason, the cached msi is not replaced and the upgrade crashes. But when I tried to call the msiexec from a Console app, the cached msi was replaced correctly. Do you have an idea why this happens?

Comment: MSI has a mutex that prevents two concurrent installation.   One msi can't install another MSI (which a recache effectively is ).  You need to run the command prior to running the new MSI.

Comment: I'm guessing that I have to run the msiexec command from the bundle somehow, before installing the major upgrade. Or, do you mean I have to create a separate app that runs the command ?

Comment: Right. Problem is I don't know that WiX BA is designed for that problem. It's going to be a tricky problem to solve.  An "oops" to your customer with an app (think of it as an upgrade prep)  might be the easiest solution to get back on track.

Comment: I thought so. The thing is, I managed to solve the issue by creating a separate minor upgrade, that installs the fixed msi (without modifying anything else). But I was wondering if the fix can be made using only one installer. Anyway, thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Yes, a minor upgrade would be pretty much the same thing.  Technically they call it a "small update" where you change the PackageCode but not the ProductCode or ProductVersion.

Comment: FWIW, sometimes I see people write custom actions that fail and block uninstalls.  I've seen this with .NET Installer Class custom actions that do services.  In one scenario the uninstall assumed the service would exist and throw an exception if it did not rolling back the uninstall.   A recache/minor upgrade would be required to fix the logic bug and permit an uninstall.  Nasty  and a good example of why one should always avoid custom actions unless they know exactly what they are doing.